# Class of graphs that contain a cycle is not axiomatizable

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic

Let $S_G=\{E\}$ be the language of graphs theory and $\Phi = \{ \forall x \neg E(x,x); \forall x \forall y [E(x,y) \rightarrow E(y,x)]\}$ be the axioms of graphs theory.
Let $\mathcal G$ be a graph. The sequence $(a_0, ... , a_{n+2})$ in $G$ is a cycle if $\mathcal G \models E(a_0,a_1) \wedge ... \wedge E(a_{n+1},a_{n+2}) \wedge E(a_{n+2},a_0) $.
How can I show that the class of all graphs that contain a cycle is not axiomatizable?

Comment: A solid overkill would be taking an ultraproduct of finite cycles of increasing lengths - if there was a formula characterizing all cycles it would be satisfied in the ultraproduct, but no formula for a cycle of length n would be satisfied. I'm sure a more elementary argument can be given though...

Comment: That's not a good definition of cycle : with this definition, any graph that contains an edge contains a cycle. You have to add some condition (e.g. $a_i \neq a_{i+2}$)

Comment: It is a very nice question. It is a pity that some trivial questions on this site have a lot of up votes and interesting ones are underestimated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume for a contradiction that there is a set $\Sigma$ of sentences such that, for any graph $\mathcal G$,
$$\mathcal G\models\Sigma\iff\mathcal G\text{ has a cycle.}$$
Let $\alpha_n$ be a sentence such that
$$\mathcal G\models\alpha_n\iff\mathcal G\text{ has no cycle of length }\le n.$$
So $\Sigma\cup\{\alpha_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is unsatisfiable. It follows by the compactness theorem that there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\Sigma\cup\{\alpha_n\}$ is unsatisfiable. But this is wrong; there is a graph whose shortest cycle has length $n+1$.

Comment: Thanks! But what is $\omega$? Or do you mean $\{\alpha_n : n < \infty \}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry about that. $\omega$ is my notation for the smallest infinite ordinal number, so $n\lt\omega$ is just a funny way of saying that $n$ is a natural number.